# Do I need to copy RootCA in machine 2 & 3's trusted root

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority

- I have 3 machines in domain and where I choose Machine1 to host asp.net web api application.
- I have create my own CA `RootCA` and put in Machine1's trusted root.
- then I issued one more certificate `X` with Machine1 fully qualified domain name from `RootCA`.
- I put  certificate `X` in Machine1's Personal root.
- I bind my asp.net web api app with  certificate `X`.
- If I browse to my asp.net web api, it's running fine and NO certificate error.
- Now when I am trying to browse my asp.net web api from Machine2 & Machine3, I am getting certificate error. if I copied `RootCA` certificate to both Machine2 & Machine3's trusted store, then NO certificate error.

It this required to copy `RootCA` certificate to both Machine2 & Machine3's trusted store? or can I eliminate this steps? perhaps I don't want to install any certificate in  Machine2 & Machine3. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your own PKI, then you have to deploy root CA certificate to all machines/applications that will utilize and/or validate certificates from your private root CA.

As an alternative, you may use 3rd party commercial CAs to get certificates, which are trusted out-of-the-box. Some 3rd party commercial CAs issue certificates for free and provide tools to automate certificate enrollment and renewal.